# C++ / Template / Explicit init of template type?

Tags: c++, templates

Assume the following dummy template:

```
template < class DataType > class Dummy
{
public:
    void init( )
    {
        m_data = DataType( 0 );
    }

private:
    DataType m_data;
};
```

Calling init will init the internal data. This does work fine when DataType is a standard data type (e.g. int or float). When DataType is a class this class must have a corresponding constructor.

Now assume DataType shall be e.g. a Complex Number represented by a suitable class. In this case it does not make sense to give the Complex number class a constructor with one argument because under normal conditions you want initialize real and imaginary part.

So my question is:
What is the best generic way to initialize a template type under consideration that the template shall be suitable to store any data type.

I think e.g. the STL must implement thinks like this but I am lost within that code.

Comment: It depends, do you have a compiler that supports C++11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example I guess you meant:

```
DataType( 0 );
```

Not:

```
Data ( 0 );
```

In any case, try:

```
m_data = DataType();
```

That will call the default constructor for a class type, or will zero-init for a built-in type.

Comment: +1: Then you'd have to require that any class passed as parameter is default-constructible, which a reasonable requirement (the standard makes it in several places, e.g. `std::map`s value-type).

Comment: Given the form of the `init` mem-func it seems default construction is a requirement of the class design.

Comment: Great ! I was not aware that built in types are initilaized to zero in this way. So I will use the default constructor.

Comment: If you have C++0x you can make use of perfect forwarding to init with any parameters

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a *default* argument as:

```
template <class T> 
class A
{
public:
    void init(T c = T()) //default argument
    {
        m_data = c;
    }
private:
    T m_data;
};
```

If template argument type `T` is a user-defined type, and it does not define a *default* constructor, then you have to pass one argument to `init()` function yourself, otherwise you will get compilation error.

This is the approach adopted by Standard Library. For example `std::vector::resize()` takes an optional argument following the same rationale as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, you are thinking in terms of "default constructible" classes here, that is, classes that can be initialized with effectively no class-specific input. The STL is written with this term in mind, and as @DanielEarwicker wrote, the default constructor is defined for built-in types as a zero-initialization.

So, to get such a feature, your complex number class must support a default constructor, i.e. a constructor without arguments.